# Transform rows from a SQL result into columns in an array

Tags: php, arrays, transform, rows

I would like to take the result from an SQL that looks like this

```
id    name    kg     date
1     ABC     3      2017-09-14
1     ABC     2      2017-09-15
2     DEF     2      2017-09-14
2     DEF     5      2017-09-15
2     DEF     5      2017-09-16
2     DEF     3      2017-09-17
3     GHI     3      2017-09-15
3     GHI     6      2017-09-17
```

And put it into an array (or something else that I can loop through) so it looks like this

```
id    name    2017-09-10    2017-09-11    2017-09-12    2017-09-13    2017-09-14    2017-09-15    2017-09-16    2017-09-17
1     ABC     3 kg          2 kg          
2     DEF     2 kg          5 kg          5 kg          3 kg
3     GHI                   3 kg                        6 kg
```

It will only hold dates from last sunday until this sunday (Active week).

I haven't worked with arrays before, but of what I have read so far I think I have to create an array inside another array to achive this? I am thinking that from the SQL result I will go through each row and push the values into right row depending if the id already exists. One id could only have unique dates.

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($resultSQL)){
    Create an array with the columns above and push the result from the SQl
    into the array on a new row or an existing column if the ID is
    already in the array.
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks.

EDIT:

Solution: I have now done like this which achives the result I wanted.

```
//create two arrays
$items=array();
$dates=array();

//loop through the SQL result and put it into the arrays
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($resultSQL)){
$ITEMNO=odbc_result($resultSQL,"id");
$ITEMNAME=odbc_result($resultSQL,"name");
$RecQtyDay=odbc_result($resultSQL,"kg");

$items[$ITEMNO] = $ITEMNAME;
$dates[$REGDATE][$ITEMNO] = $RecQtyDay;
}

//sort the dates array
ksort($dates);

//loop through and print out dates array within the item array
foreach ($items as $ITEMNO => $ITEMNAME) {
echo "$ITEMNO $ITEMNAME ";
foreach ($dates as $REGDATE => $values) {
    if (isset($values[$ITEMNO])) echo "$REGDATE $values[$ITEMNO]";
}
echo"<BR>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you fetch your query results, build *two* arrays, one with all the items, and another that's grouped by date with values for any items that have records for each date.

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($resultSQL)) {
    $items[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    $dates[$row['date']][$row['id']] = $row['kg'];
}
```

Sort the dates/values array by key (date)

```
ksort($dates);
```

Then loop over your array of items to generate the rows. Within each row, loop over the array of dates and output the value for that id and date.

```
foreach ($items as $id => $name) {
    echo "$id   $name";
    foreach ($dates as $date => $values) {
        if (isset($values[$id])) echo "$value kg";
    }
}
```

This output won't be neatly formatted, but I don't know exactly how you're planning to output this, so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am close but I have some issues with the $kg. I will output the same $kg for every date.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the complete code and the output I got. Are you able to see where I have failed?

Comment: I realized I wasn't handling the kg from the array just took the static value. So now it is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry I didn't reply earlier, I was asleep. :-)